# Vue: Cannot Read Property Image of Null

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue v2.5.13 and I've been getting the following error lately:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null"

found in

---> <Coin> at src/components/Coin.vue
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Here's my script file:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currency: {
        symbol: 'ads',
        name: 'da',
        image: 'dadadfda',
        smallImg: 'ad',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
   ...
  },
  mounted() {
   ...
  },
};
</script>
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div>
...
<img :src="currency.image" :alt="currency.name">
...
</div>
```

Whilst I used `{{ currency.image }}` on the html and it prints the correct value but still gives the error and mounted() doesn't run up at all.

The Vue Dev tools show:

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that you have no other initialization or mutation logic for `currency`? I don't see what could be causing the problem given only the code snippets you've provided. Perhaps consider showing us your `mounted` logic.

Comment: Nope. I just update values of currency's properties and nothing else.

Comment: So you updated `currency` to `null` somewhere.

Comment: Nope it's not updated at all.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much more we can do for you given the amount of information you've provided to us. My only recommendation is that you slowly strip out functionality until you isolate the issue, or to provide more snippets of your code so that we can see what's going on. Your code's behavior absolutely indicates that you're setting `currency` to null, but you insist that this isn't the case. Thus, you're either overlooking a spot in your code where this is happening, or you're encountering a strange issue with Vue itself that does not currently exist in Vue's issue tracker.